# unexplainable occurance of "object references an unsaved transient instance"

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a really strange behaviour with unsaved transient instance in Hibernate (4.2.1)

The entity I am trying to save is called Prozess and it has several similar looking sets attatched.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="id.prozess")
@Sort (type=SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<EkPreis> ekPreise = new TreeSet<EkPreis>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="id.prozess")
@Sort (type=SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<VkPreis> vkPreise = new TreeSet<VkPreis>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="id.prozess")
@Sort (type=SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<ProzessKommunikation> prozessKommunikationen = new TreeSet<ProzessKommunikation>();


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="id.prozess")
@Sort (type=SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<ProzessClusterVerarbeitet> verarbeiteteCluster = new TreeSet<ProzessClusterVerarbeitet>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="id.prozess")
@Sort (type=SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<ProzessBausteinVerarbeitet> verarbeiteteBausteine = new TreeSet<ProzessBausteinVerarbeitet>();
```

The ids of the objects in those sets are all built identically. They use composed Ids made up of the Prozess and an Article (of course they each use their own object for that VkPreisId, EkPreisId and so on)

All these sets aur usually handled manually and the prozess itself is only persisted, when its status is changed.

I now have a fire and forget link that does exactly that. It loads the process, changes the status and then calls makePersistent on the process. None of the sets are touched.

The set prozessKommunikationen is empty to begin with and nothing changes about that. I checked the set inside the makePersistent routine and it was empty. Yet, when makePersistent is called I get the following error:

object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: de.toom.model.ProzessKommunikation

And when I debug where the exception is thrown in hibernate I get the ID of a ProzessKommunikation object that simply does not exist (and the object is otherwise empty). What exists however is a VkPreis object with the identical id (meaning the identical prozess and Article).

It seems that somehow hibernate is getting mixed up here and I have no idea why and more important how to stop that behaviour.

---

OK, I found the problem although I still do not completely understand it.

There was an object in the Session that had a reference to an empty ProzessKommunikation (with id) created by an init-routine. That class however is nowhere visible in the Prozess.
It connects to a view in the database and is therefore not intended to be used for updates or inserts anyway.
That class has many_to_one relationships to VkPreis and ProzessKommunikation but the reverse reference in VkPreis and ProzessKommunikation do not exist.
So VkPreis and ProzessKommunikation should not know if there are any vkPreisViews connected to them.
So when I tried to persist Prozess I had not expected that the reverse direction is called causing problems with unsafed instances.

Evicting the vkPreisViews befor the makePersist eliminated my nasty problem.